# How to force Hibernate-Envers to use quotes around fields name?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, double-quotes, hibernate-envers

I have a table with properties defined like this : 
`@Column(name="\"SERIAL#\"")`

When Hibernate inserts data, everything works fine.
But it comes to Hibernate-Envers(HE), HE forgets to surround the field name with doublequotes.

How can i force it to use the doublequotes aroud the fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solving the problem, i manage to not use the '#' in the field name thus neither Hibernate nor Hibernate Envers have to escape the field name.

**EDIT**:

In fact it's a bug in Hibernate Envers 3.6.2.Final. It should be solved later.

**EDIT 2**:
The bug has been fixed in Hibernate Envers 3.6.3 and Hibernate Envers 4.0.0Alpha.

**EDIT 3**:
The bug has been fixed in Hibernate Core 3.6.4.Final.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to use double quotes, or do you want to escape the name? If you just want to escape, use backticks (`) and Hibernate will convert it to whatever mechanism your database uses for escaping. So, your example would be:

```
@Column(name="`SERIAL#`")
```

Just out of curiosity: why do you need a # in a column name? I always thought that special chars are a bad idea in identifiers :-)

Comment: i'm building a small monitoring tool for databases. One of the database i monitor exposes tables with those kind of characters.

Comment: Hibernate understands the backticks but Hibernate *Envers* doesn't.

Comment: I am using PostgeSQL, which uses double quotes and *not* backticks. However, Hibernate is using backticks anyway. Can you please take a look at my [situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67171073/how-do-i-configure-hibernate-to-use-double-quotes)?